# Conditionnally formatting the background color of a table (formattable in R)

Tags: r, formattable

I have a table similar to the below:

```
library(tibble)
library(formattable)

mytable <- tibble(
id = c(NA, 748, 17, 717, 39, 734, 10, 762),
NPS = c(65, 63, 56, 62, 73, 80, 50, 54),
`NPS Chge vs. month ago` = c(-2, -5, -2, -8, -1, 6, 7, -9),
`Cumulative Response` = c(766, 102, 154, 81, 239, 79, 50, 61),
`Response Rate` = c(0.25, 0.24, 0.25, 0.34, 0.21, 0.34, 0.32, 0.27),
`Response for Month` = c(161, 43, 7, 37, 7, 32, 15, 20)
)

formattable(mytable)
```

[image]

And I wish to set a conditional formatting to the background of the rows such that if the NPS score is below 60 the background is set to red, otherwise it's set to green. In my limited knowledge of HTML I figured I could use "td". Unfortunately it appears to mess the format of the table as a whole:

```
html_tag <- "td"
my_format <- formatter(html_tag, style = x ~ ifelse(mytable$NPS < 60, "background-color:red", "background-color:green"))

formattable(mytable, list(
  area(col = 2:6) ~ my_format
))
```

[image]

The headers of the table are no longer aligned with the rest of the rows. What am I doing wrong? What should I use instead of "td"?

Comment: Running into the same problem. Looks like calls to the `td` tag insert either (1) new formatted columns or (2) new blank ones and modify the originals with the color formatting.

Comment: Tested this with different styles with custom formatter objects. The result holds regardless of the use of `area()` vs a name-specified single column and is independent of what style element is called. `td` is duplicated regardless of whether you're trying to alter color or something else on the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the background color conditionally without using HTML. A simple version of code without extra aesthetics could be like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
tibble(
  id = c(NA, 748, 17, 717, 39, 734, 10, 762),
  NPS = c(65, 63, 56, 62, 73, 80, 50, 54),
  `NPS Chge vs. month ago` = c(-2, -5, -2, -8, -1, 6, 7, -9),
  `Cumulative Response` = c(766, 102, 154, 81, 239, 79, 50, 61),
  `Response Rate` = c(0.25, 0.24, 0.25, 0.34, 0.21, 0.34, 0.32, 0.27),
  `Response for Month` = c(161, 43, 7, 37, 7, 32, 15, 20)
) %>%
  formattable(align = rep("c", ncol(.)),
              list(
                `NPS` = formatter("span", style = ~ style (display = "block",
                                                           `background-color` = ifelse(NPS < 60, "red", "green"))) 
              )
  )
```

[image]